# Android dialog height and width is behaving unexpectedly

Tags: android, xml

I have custom dialog now when i run the code it behaving unexpectedly. It shrinks it's height and width. So please help me to get actual width and height as specified in the layout file.
The xml of custom dialog is added below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#143849"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/plainwhite" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="10" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/plainwhite" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FLIGHT DETAILS" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/placeTravel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Kannur - Trivandrum" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateOfTravel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="wed, dec-10 " />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="Depart" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/departTV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:hint=":Kannur" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="Arrive" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/arriveTV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:hint=":Trivandrum" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="Duration" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/durationTV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:hint=":02h 15m nonstop" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:text="Price" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/travelPriceTV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:hint=":$450 per Adult" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/planType"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="6"
                android:hint="(Non refundable)" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the code calling the dialog is added below

```
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.customDialogStyle);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.flight_info_dialog);
```

what I am getting is shown below

[image]

Any help will be appreciable

customdialogStyle code is added below

```
<style name="customDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Post code of R.style.customDialogStyle xml file

Comment: and you could mention what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution adding the main linear layout inside a relative layout  solved the problem.Added the xml changes.

But I don't know why it shows such a weird behavior . If any one know the reason please share to help. Thanks for all who tried to help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#143849"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/plainwhite" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/plainwhite" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FLIGHT DETAILS" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/placeTravel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Kannur - Trivandrum" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/dateOfTravel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="wed, dec-10 " />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:text="Depart" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/departTV"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:hint=":Kannur" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:text="Arrive" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/arriveTV"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:hint=":Trivandrum" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:text="Duration" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/durationTV"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:hint=":02h 15m nonstop" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4"
                    android:text="Price" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/travelPriceTV"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:hint=":$450 per Adult" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="10" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="4" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/planType"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:hint="(Non refundable)" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your goal, then you'll need something like this for your style:

```
<style name="customDialogStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <!-- item name="android:windowBackground">#00000000</item -->
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```